# how to get all fields in the query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate-functions, mongoose-schema

I am trying in this aggregation is working but not get all fields how to get all fields any suggestion me i wright any wrong this query please check

```js
db.lights.aggregate({
  $match: {
    CREATE_DATE: {
      $gte: ISODate("2018-01-24T20:05:30.000Z"),
      $lt: ISODate("2018-02-24T20:05:30.000Z")
    }
  }
}, {
  $addFields: {
    offduration: {
      $divide: [{
        $subtract: ["$RECEIVEDDATE", "$CREATE_DATE"]
      }, 3600000]
    }
  }
}, {
  "$group": {
    _id: {
      SWITCHID: "$SWITCHID",
      STATUS: "$STATUS"
    },
    avgduration: {
      $avg: "$offduration"
    }
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
    SWITCHID: 1,
    CREATE_DATE: 1,
    RECEIVEDDATE: 1,
    STATUS: 1,
    avgduration: '$avgduration',
    offduration: '$offduration'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
db.lights.aggregate({
    $match: {
        CREATE_DATE: {
            $gte: ISODate("2018-01-24T20:05:30.000Z"),
            $lt: ISODate("2018-02-24T20:05:30.000Z")
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        offduration: {
            $divide: [{
                $subtract: ["$RECEIVEDDATE", "$CREATE_DATE"]
            }, 3600000]
        }
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        _id: {
            SWITCHID: "$SWITCHID",
            STATUS: "$STATUS"
        },
        avgduration: {
            $avg: "$offduration"
        },
        SWITCHID: {
            $first: "$SWITCHID"
        },
        CREATE_DATE: {
            $first: "$CREATE_DATE"
        },
        RECEIVEDDATE: {
            $first: "$RECEIVEDDATE"
        },
        STATUS: {
            $first: "$STATUS"
        },
        offduration: {
            $first: "$offduration"
        },
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        SWITCHID: 1,
        CREATE_DATE: 1,
        RECEIVEDDATE: 1,
        STATUS: 1,
        avgduration: '$avgduration',
        offduration: '$offduration'
    }
})
```

You can use $$ROOT also, It'll add entire object inside data. You have to refer using `data.key`

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            SWITCHID: "$SWITCHID",
            STATUS: "$STATUS"
        },
        data: {
            $first: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Rahul Sharma great...its working but
my output is
"_id" : {
  "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/10",
  "STATUS" : "LIGHTS OFF"
 },
 "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/10",
 "CREATE_DATE" : ISODate("2018-02-09T01:34:08.088Z"),
 "RECEIVEDDATE" : ISODate("2018-02-09T01:36:08.088Z"),
 "STATUS" : "LIGHTS OFF",
 "avgduration" : 0.03333333333333333,
 "offduration" : 0.03333333333333333
}
how to remove this fields
"_id" : {
  "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/10",
  "STATUS" : "LIGHTS OFF"
 },

Comment: SWICHID AND STATUS repeat how to remove

Comment: In $project change _id to 0.

Comment: you can use `$cond` for that.

Comment: @ Rahul Sharma i write the query using $cond its working but how to add the previous query in this query 
{"$group" : {     _id: {         SWITCHID: "$SWITCHID"     },     on_minus_off: { $sum:{ "$cond": [         { "$eq": ["$STATUS", "LIGHTS OFF"] },         "$avgduration",         { $subtract: [ 0, "$avgduration" ] }     ]}} }}